# How to connect IoT hub to Kafka enabled event hub?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-eventhub

If IoT hub can have built in service endpoints for Event hub service then can it send all its messages to Kafka enabled Event hub, if yes how?

Simple link of documentation would also be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can route device-to-cloud messages sent to your IoT hub to one or more endpoints by configuring routes - in addition to the built-in endpoint, you can route messages to Event Hubs, Service  Bus, or blob storage. To get started, take a look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-d2c. There's also a routing tutorial you can follow: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/iot-hub/tutorial-routing